# Azure App Service Application Settings - Can't see Key vault Reference Details

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service

When accessing Application Settings I can only see `Key vault Reference` and a red cross but no information why it does not work.

[image]

Edit mode:

[image]

I would like to see it like this:

[image]

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58113892/3850405

PS: I got the connection working but I still can't see any error. The question is therefore not related to why there is an error, simply why I can't see any details like others users.

[image]

Comment: Try to refresh the whole page, click the edit button, then wait. It should show the details no matter it connect success or failed.

Comment: @BowmanZhu Waited for 20 minutes, nothing happens and every request has been processed long ago.

Comment: On my side it can show the details. I also dont know what happened now...

Comment: I have got the same problem. Key Vault Reference Details are not displayed. Did anyone find the root cause for this? Have you been able to find an answer @Ogglas?

Comment: @MalteLantin anything on this?