# Application setting of Key vault reference missing in logicapp

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

Searching for key vault reference application in configuration blade of logicapp

**Error@ Key Vault reference was not able to resolved**

TO resolve this error I am searching for configuration blade in logicapp but didn't find it out

Am I missing anything here?

Comment: Yep, you’re missing more information. Where does the error occur? What does your flow look like? Etc. screenshots help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of my understanding you are unable to find configuration blade in logic App .**You are facing this issue because your searching configuration blade in Consumption logic App.**
As shown in below Consumption logic App's menu there is no Configuration option.

[image]

Open your Standard logic App, **in your Standard logic app's menu, under settings you can find Configuration as shown in below image.**

[image]

To resolve key vault reference error  configure your created keyvault in standard logicapp as shown in below image then you can able to find keyvault reference by following [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58105357/how-to-resolve-keyvault-references-to-secrets-via-application-settings-in-functi) link

[image]